# How to make a poll in python with lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a poll as an exercise that uses user input to find where people want to go on vacation. Here is my code so far:

```
done = False
places = []
while done == False:
    dreamvacation = input("What is your dream vacation? ")
    if dreamvacation == "quit":
        for item in places:
            number = places.count(item)
            if number == 1:
                print("{} occured in the list 1 time.".format(item))
            else:
                print("{} occured in the list {} times.".format(item, number))
                while number > 0:
                    places.remove(item)
                    number -= 1
        done = True
    places.append(dreamvacation)
```

Basically it does the poll and each time someone enters something, it adds it to the list. Then when someone says quit, it counts the items and says something different depending on how many times the vacation spot occurred. If it occurs multiple times, I had the other duplicates removed after they were counted using a `while` loop. But, when it removes duplicates, the whole list shifted and the index spot moved forward thus skipping a spot. For example:

```
[a(index is here),b,c,a,]
```

After the counting, both `a`'s would be removed and the index position would move forward:

```
[b,c(index is here)]
```

How can I make it so the index position stays in the same spot while the list shifts?

If I can do this, then I could have my program remove duplicates and singles after the letter is counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to delete entries of `places`. It only makes it hard to keep track. Please see the following example. I re-structured your code a little bit as well:

```
done = False
places = []

# user input stage
while not done:
    dream_loc = input('where to go? ')
    if dream_loc == 'quit':
        done = True
    else:
        places.append(dream_loc)

# counting stage
for loc in set(places):
    count = places.count(loc)
    if count == 1:
        print("{} occured in the list 1 time.".format(loc))
    else:
        print("{} occured in the list {} times.".format(loc, count))
```